# PubTator unable to process query

Tags: python, python-requests, pubmed-api

I'm trying to submit a query to PubTator, following the example code they provide in their [API documentation](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/pubtator/api.html).

Here is the code I'm running:

```
text = ('Humboldtia vahliana Wight. is an endangered species belonging to the '
'family Leguminosae (subfamily Caesalpinioideae). Though the plant propagates '
'through seeds, low seed setting, seed infestation, poor viability of seed, '
'reduction in natural regeneration of seedlings as well as anthropogenic '
'activities like overexploitation, habitat destruction and fragmented '
'distribution in localities are the major factors hindering the survival of the '
'species. Hence, strategies must be devised urgently for the conservation of this '
'species as these recalcitrant seeds do not contribute significantly to the seed '
'bank. The present attempt was to understand the seed physiology and biochemistry '
'during embryogenesis and embryo desiccation. H. vahliana seeds took 120 days '
'after anthesis to acquire full maturity. Immature seeds had higher moisture '
'content (87.40%) which gradually reduced during maturity and reached 55.42% '
'at the time of seed shed a true recalcitrant behavior of the seeds. Freshly '
'fallen mature seeds showed an optimal germination percentage of 82.32% which '
'was severely affected by the decrease in seed moisture content and the critical '
'moisture content was found to be 33.63% in which the percentage of germination '
'was only 30%. Cell membrane damage of seed was found to cause quick loss of '
'seed viability. The LC-MS/MS analysis showed insignificant amounts of ribose, '
'arabinose and trehalose but a significant accumulation of fructose in the mature '
'embryos rather than glucose and sucrose. Embryo drying significantly reduced the '
'level of these sugars including the stress related trehalose indicating the lack '
'of biosynthetic machinery to counter desiccation stress in these recalcitrant '
'seeds.')

r = requests.post(
    'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/pubtator-api/annotations/annotate/submit/All',
    data=text.encode('utf-8'))
session_num = r.text

status_code = 404
while status_code == 404:
    result = requests.get(
    'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/pubtator-api/annotations/annotate/retrieve/' + session_num)
    status_code = result.status_code

print(status_code, result.text)
```

The API documentation says that the server will return a 404 code until the request is done being processed, which is why I wrote a `while` loop to keep checking the status code. However, when I let it run, it finishes with a status code of `500`, and the message `"We have trouble processing your query"`.

I haven't been able to find any information about what this actually means, and as far as I can tell, I'm following the example code's request format exactly. Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: HTTP status [500](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) means that a server-side error occurred. This is intended to indicate that the client can't do anything to fix it, but many APIs return this code as the result of unexpected invalid data.

Comment: Your `while` loop is hammering the API. Please add some sort of delay, e.g. `time.sleep(10)`. It's possible that you're overloading the server or triggering it to block your IP. Normally, the status code for too many requests is 429, but not all APIs return it properly.

Comment: Also note that the [JSON input format](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/research/bionlp/APIs/format/) has properties `text`, `sourcedb` and `sourceid`, while your input has only `text`. The documentation is incomplete, but this may be causing your problem.

Comment: Actually, you aren't submitting JSON, or any other of the defined input formats.

Comment: Formatting it as JSON and submitting request via `curl` resulted in a 500 status as well. I bet the request is malformed and the server doesn't handle it gracefully. You should contact the admin for more info.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it! The format of my requests is identical to the requests in the sample code from the documentation, so it's helpful to know that other formats with `curl` also didn't work. I wasn't able to find a forum or a github, which is why I posted here, but I'll try looking again for a contact. EDIT: There is contact info for the developers at the bottom of the webpage, I'll post again once I have an update!